# Common words used in highschool mathematics in German

Tags: resource, mathematics

I will soon be writing an exam in German on math, and I have a bit of difficulty knowing the translation between of what the questions are at times due to the terminologies. Could someone suggest a resource where I can learn of the common German words for math at highschool to undergraduate level?

Test will cover (probably):

- Basic Calculus
- Algebra
- Geometry
- Solid Shapes
- A little number theory

Comment: I don't mean to be snarky, yet... what about a normal math book as used for lectures on whatever math topic interests you? Put those things which are not clear into deepl or whatever online translation service suits you and you will be fine. In my (inverted) experience, the language in science or math classes is very limited and well defined compared to after-hour pub chat or everyday life.

Comment: I actually took a German for reading knowledge in Mathematics once upon a time. It wasn't high school level though. It's not just the words you have to learn, but at least some of the grammar and certain expressions. As mentioned in the previous comment, it's still easy compared to being able to understand everyday conversation. I don't know if the question can be answered without more information on what the test will cover; are we talking basic algebra, calculus, geometry, business math? Even knowing that, planetmaker's plan seems good and is more or less what I did at the time.

Comment: I'd recommend (not only to familiarize yourselves with the terminology, but also to refresh the topic in general) working through *Abiturprüfungen*, for example here: https://www.abiturloesung.de Terminology that is not obvious from there should be an easy fix helped by DeepL or Google T.

Comment: There is no real book for this. It's a pretty niche exam. It is for internationals who want to study in Germany @planetmaker

Comment: @SBrian yes. That's why I recommend a normal introductory book on algebra or analysis in German. E. g. https://www.uibk.ac.at/mathematik/algebra/media/teaching/lineare-algebra.pdf (no recommendation, just the first I found online)

Comment: This is incredibly broad and I think the only solution to know what exactly is expected from you is to harvest the solutions of the previous years for terminology.

Answer (score 1):

I found a wikipage on it interestingly enough:

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_mathematischer_Symbole#Funktionen

They have symbols on every topic